# Java PreparedStatement:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:parameter index out of range

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I'm try to execute a SQL query using java PreparedStatement in JAVA 8 and code blow

```
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URl,user,"");
        String sql = "Select Grade from XS_KC where Snum=？ and Cnum=?";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, "020101");
        pst.setString(2, "102");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.print(rs.getString(1));
        }
```

I get the fllowing error:`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:parameter index out of range`
But if i use

```
stat = con.createStatement();
rs = stat.executeQuery("Select Grade from XS_KC where Snum='020101' and Cnum='101'");
```

I can get the result
What's wrong??

Comment: You have different column names, different values (101 vs 102)... makes me wonder what the actual code and SQL statements are

Comment: i am sorry . i forget to change column names. but it's not the key. because i just translate it to English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `？` in your query is Unicode 0x1FFF rather than 0x3F00 (question mark). Try:

```
String sql = "Select Grade from XS_KC where Snum=? and Cnum=?";
```

Comment: Thanks sir. Maybe this is the sadness of people whose native language is not English